# embedding a <video> tag within a <p> tag breaks the <video> tag in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, html5-video

I found this problem with the HTML5 video tag and it has me very puzzled.  If I embed a video tag within a paragraph tags, it stops working properly in some browsers.

Can anybody throw any light on this?

The video tag is a bit tricky, so the problem takes a bit of explanation.  To illustrate it, here's an HTML5 page that you can run.  It uses a handy .mp4 test video from a Microsoft website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>video with no para</title></head>
  <body>
    <video controls>
    <source src="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/videoformatsupport/big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p_high.mp4"
        type='video/mp4'/>
      These words and the button below should not be visible
      in an HTML5 browser
      <form method='get' action='www.microft.com'>
          <input type='submit' value='MS Home'</form>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

An HTML5 video tag can have one or more source tags, each giving a video in some format.  The browser will display one video that it can handle.  To cope wih browsers that don't understand HTML5, a video tag can contain extra stuff outside the source tags.  An HTML5 browser should ignore this extra stuff.  A non-HTML5 browser should ignore any tags it doesn't understand (in this case video and source), so it will ignore the video and render just the other stuff.  In the real world, the other stuff would usually provide some way to download and play the video.  In this example, the other stuff is a bit of text and a form that displays a button.

So, different browsers will display this page in different ways.  The latest versions of Chrome and IE understand HTML5 and they know how to render a .mp4 source, so they should present the video.  They SHOULD NOT display the text or the button.

The latest version of Firefox handles HTML5 but doesn't know how to play a .mp4.  It needs a video in ogg format.  It handles this problem by displaying a black box where the video should be.  However, once again, it should not display the text or the button.

Older versions of these browsers that don’t do HTML5 should display just the text and the button.

The HTML shown above works as expected.  The problem happens if I wrap a para around the video section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>video with para</title></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <video controls>
      <source src="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/videoformatsupport/big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p_high.mp4"
          type='video/mp4'/>
    These words and the button below should not be visible
    in an HTML5 browser
    <form method='get' action='www.microft.com'>
        <input type='submit' value='MS Home'</form>
      </video>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

IE version 9 works properly – it displays the video with no text and no button.

Chrome version 17.0.963.56 m displays the video, ignores the text, as it should, BUT it displays the button below the video panel.

Firefox 9.0.1 displays the black box as before, but it also displays the button.

If this happened with just one browser, I would just assume it was a simple bug.  What puzzles me is that in both Chrome and Firefox break in the same way.

Of course, you could argue that wrapping a video in para tags makes no sense, but it seems to me that it shouldn’t cause a problem.  Also, I wonder what other wrappers might break it.

[image: Firebug shows how the HTML is interpreted]

Comment: I took a screenshot of firebug view of the source. It is indeed surprising (note: my image upload need to be approved so you might not see it immediately or at all)

Comment: You might get the impression from the answers that any element in place of the `<p>` that only expects phrasing content (e.g. `<span>`) would also cause the same breakage. This is not the case. Only the `<p>` element behaves this way.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that a `form` element is not valid as a descendant of a `p` element. Browsers try to interpret the document the best they can, which results in the DOM shown in the screenshot, with the `form` element appearing as a *sibling* of the `p` element, rather than a descendant.

You can follow this through in the HTML5 spec. The section concerning the [`p` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-p-element.html) tells us that it expects "phrasing content". The section on phrasing content tells us exactly what elements fall into that category. `form` is not one of them.

If you have a look at the section on the [`form` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), it shows that the `form` element falls into the "flow content" category.

You can confirm this further by using the W3C validator. I've uploaded the two example pages to a web server ([valid](http://jamesallardice.com/so/valid.html) and [invalid](http://jamesallardice.com/so/invalid.html)) so you can see the validation results:

- [Validation of first (valid) example](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.jamesallardice.com/so/valid.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)
- [Validation of second (invalid) example](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.jamesallardice.com/so/invalid.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.2)

Note that in both cases I've modified the code very slightly, to close the `input` element which is unclosed in both examples in the question.

Comment: Rather than as a descendant, but yeah. This is most likely the case.

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot that it was a child of the `video` element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:very well formatted question!

Now I should say that you made me do a lot of research.

First of all I found that the W3 schools specification mentions that the `<video>`  tag can contain only plain text (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)). However this was argued with in another [reference](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_video_tag.cfm).

Now about your problem: you can not use any block-level html elements in the `<p>` tag according to html [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). However you are using a form, which is a block-level element according to this [list](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html). This means that you write invalid html and browsers are free to misinterpret it.

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the WHATWG's documentation on HTML5 as they're the ones writing HTML5, not anybody else. Your W3C link doesn't even come close as you're linking to the HTML 4.01 spec!

Comment: @BoltClock Which link are you actually speaking of? The one that says `HTML5 <video> Tag` you mean?

Comment: Your last paragraph links to HTML 4 references.

Comment: Yes but in it there is nothing html 5 specific. Both links link to statements that are cross-valid even in HTML 5. Truth is that the particular problem the OP is speaking of does not have to do with video tag itself and is not HTML 5 specific.